# Port translation with iptables

Tags: networking, iptables, nat

I need to port forward with translation on a range of ports.

If I do:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i ppp0 -p tcp --dport 2000:3000 -j DNAT --to 192.168.1.41:4000-5000
```

it doesn't work as it should. If I connect to WANIP:2001 it tries to connect to 192.168.1.41:4000 instead that 192.168.1.41:4001.

Is there any way to do this without creating 1000 iptables rules?

Comment: What do you need this for?

Comment: I need to make a router

Comment: What?  I am sorry, but that saying you want a router did not  clear up things at all.  Is there some reason why you can't just NAT everything to 192.168.1.41?

Comment: because it's not a DMZ :)

Comment: It's not working as you *expected*, but it's working as it *should*. NAT to a range will select *any* unused port in the range, and *not* do a 1-to-1 mapping.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do range mapping like you are trying to do. You could write a 3 line script to generate the rules for you, but that would be a bad hack. I really think you are on the wrong track here. @Zoredache already tried to suggest this might not be the right solution at all. Please be more explicit with your situation so we can recommend something.

You probably do need some kind of NAT, but there are several kinds including full pass throughs that can route traffic over the full range of ports both directions to one machine, and other machines can tag along for one direction. Give us your architecture and we can suggest a proper solution. Setting up 1000 iptables rules isn't it.